# Advice, tools to match parenthesis in SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle10g, syntax-highlighting

Can someone can tell me a nice approach to checking how, and where, parenthesis may be missing (or be in excess) in a query such as the following?

For example, this query returns error that it is missing right parenthesis. But where??? !

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT X.*, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (SELECT ORG_UNIT, QUEUE_NAME, CASE_STATUS, AGENT_ROLE, COUNT(*) AS CASE_COUNT 
   FROM 
   (    
     SELECT ORG_UNIT, QUEUE_NAME, CREATION_TIMESTAMP, CASE_STATUS, AGENT_ROLE
     FROM 
     (   SELECT OU.NAME AS ORG_UNIT,            D.NAME AS QUEUE_NAME, 
                WS.NAME AS CASE_STATUS,  C.ASSIGNED_TO AS AGENT_ID,  C.CREATION_TIMESTAMP AS CREATION_TIMESTAMP,
                CASE NVL(C.ASSIGNED_TO, -1) WHEN -1 THEN 'Unassigned' ELSE RU.ROLE_NAME END AS AGENT_ROLE 
           FROM CASES C 
           JOIN ORGANIZATION_UNITS OU ON OU.ID = C.ORGUNIT_ID       
           JOIN WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS ON WS.ID = C.STATUS_ID 
           JOIN DOMAINS D ON D.ID = C.DOMAIN_ID 
           JOIN DOMAINS DP ON DP.ID = D.PARENT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT C.ASSIGNED_TO AS AGENT_ID, RL.NAME AS ROLE_NAME 
                                  FROM CASES C 
                                    JOIN DOMAINS D ON D.ID = C.DOMAIN_ID 
                                    JOIN DOMAINS DP ON DP.ID = D.PARENT_ID 
                                    JOIN USER_GROUP_RELATIONS UGR ON UGR.USER_ID = C.ASSIGNED_TO 
                                    JOIN GRP_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS GODRR ON (GODRR.GROUP_ID = (SELECT MAX(UGR.GROUP_ID) 
                                                                                                                                                                   FROM USER_GROUP_RELATIONS UGR 
                                                                                                                                                                 WHERE   UGR.USER_ID = C.ASSIGNED_TO) 
                                                                                                                   AND GODRR.DOMAIN_ID =C.DOMAIN_ID
                                                                                                                   AND GODRR.ORGANIZATION_ID = C.ORGUNIT_ID) 
  JOIN ROLES RL ON RL.ID = (SELECT MAX(GODRR.ROLE_ID) 
                                                  FROM GRP_ORG_DOM_ROLE_RELATIONS GODRR 
                                                WHERE GODRR.GROUP_ID = UGR.GROUP_ID 
                                                     AND GODRR.ORGANIZATION_ID = C.ORGUNIT_ID AND GODRR.DOMAIN_ID = C.DOMAIN_ID)            
                                WHERE DP.NAME='DD') RU ON RU.AGENT_ID = C.ASSIGNED_TO 
       WHERE DP.NAME='DD' 
     )  WHERE 1=1
   ) 
   GROUP BY ORG_UNIT, QUEUE_NAME, CASE_STATUS, AGENT_ROLE  
   ORDER BY ORG_UNIT, QUEUE_NAME, CASE_STATUS, AGENT_ROLE order by ORG_UNIT asc ) X ) WHERE RN > 0 AND RN <= 10
```

Comment: [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) has nice syntax highlighting, otherwise I'm sure you can take the time it took to post the question and start indenting and looking for mis-matches.

Comment: Just work on proper indentation and the missing paranthesis should present themselves easily.

Comment: Put all sub-selects each in a separate document, and start counting.

Comment: This must be a joke! You're using select statements for joining conditions. How is anybody supposed to know where the fault comes up?

Comment: @entek: It's called a derived table, and they're very common.

Comment: `WHERE 1=1` - that is definitely worth checking:)

Comment: Well, if you are able to produce such a query, you are considered to be able to read it, understand it, or **at least** indent it.

Comment: The last line has 2 `ORDER BY`. Try adding a ) just before the second one.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I didnt say there's anything strange on that query, but how is anyone of us supposed to find where the fault comes up, without knowing his db-structure? Maybe it's just a mis-spelled column name in a join-select-condition?

Comment: @entek: There could be other errors, but right now there's a missing `)` somewhere.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: correct indention might make it easier :)

Comment: @entek: I *will* agree with you there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crimson Edit and many other text editors and IDEs have brace matching.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Editor

If brace match, but are nested wrong, you may need to change your indentation strategy.

Also, code formatting tools sometimes can make it clear where you missed a paren or nested wrong.

Here is one online place where you can paste in your code to see it reformatted.

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew. I will be careful with the indentation hereafter. Thanks.